# Email not being sent and alert dialog not getting displayed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am building a flutter application and I'm using Firebase to manage my users. I have created a Reset password page, on which the users can enter their email and the reset password email will be sent to the registered users.

But my flutter onPressed code is not working. Due to which the reset password email is not getting sent and the Alert Boxes are also not getting displayed.

My code :

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:secure_pass/services/auth/auth_exceptions.dart';
import 'package:secure_pass/utilities/dialogs/error_dialog.dart';

class ResetPasswordView extends StatefulWidget {
  const ResetPasswordView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ResetPasswordView> createState() => _ResetPasswordViewState();
}

class _ResetPasswordViewState extends State<ResetPasswordView> {
  final _email = TextEditingController();

  Widget buildButton() {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text('Reset Password'),
      onPressed: () {
        passwordReset;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _email.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future passwordReset() async{
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: _email.text);
      showDialog(
        context: context, 
        builder: (context) {
          return const AlertDialog(
            content : Text('Password reset link sent! Check your email'),
          );
        }
      );
    } on UserNotFoundAuthException {
        await showErrorDialog(
          context,
          'User not found',
        );
    } on InvalidEmailAuthException {
        await showErrorDialog(
          context,
          'This is an invalid email address',
        );
      } on GenericAuthException {
        await showErrorDialog(
          context,
          'Please try again',
        );
      }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Reset Password'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[200],
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 23.0),
            child: Text(
              "Enter your Email and we will send you a password reset link",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle( 
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
            
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),

          //email textfield
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _email,
                      enableSuggestions: false,
                      autocorrect: false,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter your email here',
                        border: InputBorder.none
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
            buildButton(),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the ()

```dart
Widget buildButton() {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text('Reset Password'),
      onPressed: () async{
       await passwordReset();//here
      },
    );
  }
```

**Edit**

```
Future passwordReset() async{
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: _email.text);
      showDialog(
        context: context, 
        builder: (context) {
          return const AlertDialog(
            content : Text('Password reset link sent! Check your email'),
          );
        }
      );
    } catch(e){
       print("e"); //add conditions here based on the exceptions
     }
  }
```

Comment: Hii @Kaushik , Now I'm getting the email and the Email sent Alert dialog is also working. But user not found, invalid email address, etc Alert dialogs are still not working. Can you please help me.

Comment: So, I'm going to have to remove the on UserNotFoundAuthException , etc and just use the Alert Dialog right ?

Comment: Yeah. That will show all errors in alert or toast